# Webpack won't compile when I use an image url in scss

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass

I'm trying to get a very simple project going with Material Design and WebPack, but I'm getting compile errors. I've been following this guide to set everything up:
https://material.io/develop/web/getting-started

I'm honestly baffled by this error. I have obviously looked online for a solution, but everything I found was related to linter. I don't use a linter.

Here's the error:

```
ERROR in ./app.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/extract-loader/lib/extractLoader.js):
SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (5:73)
  3 | import ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___ from "./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js";
  4 | import ___CSS_LOADER_GET_URL_IMPORT___ from "./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/getUrl.js";
> 5 | var ___CSS_LOADER_URL_IMPORT_0___ = new URL("./images/bckgnd_light.jpg", import.meta.url);
    |                                                                          ^
  6 | var ___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___ = ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___(___CSS_LOADER_API_NO_SOURCEMAP_IMPORT___);
  7 | var ___CSS_LOADER_URL_REPLACEMENT_0___ = ___CSS_LOADER_GET_URL_IMPORT___(___CSS_LOADER_URL_IMPORT_0___);
  8 | // Module
```

My app.scss file only consists of:

```
#content {
    background: url('./images/bckgnd_light.jpg') #e8e5d7;
}
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./app.scss', './app.js'],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'bundle.css',
            },
          },
          {loader: 'extract-loader'},
          {loader: 'css-loader'},
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [
                  autoprefixer()
                ]
              }
            } 
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              // Prefer Dart Sass
              implementation: require('sass'),

              // See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/804
              webpackImporter: false,
              sassOptions: {
                includePaths: ['./node_modules'],
              },
            },
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        loader: 'url-loader'
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "materialdesigntest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material/button": "^14.0.0",
    "@material/ripple": "^14.0.0",
    "@material/textfield": "^14.0.0",
    "material-components-web": "^14.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "extract-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack serve"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging I found this thread:
https://github.com/peerigon/extract-loader/issues/111

Changing the `css-loader` to this solved the issue for me:

```
{
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    esModule: false
  }
},
```

Comment: That didn't do it for me.  [There's another option for parsing urls](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#url):  `options: { url: false }`

Comment: Works for me. Thanks, Fabian.